# How to mock axios for formik submit?

Tags: mocking, jestjs, axios, formik

The problem I'm running into is not being able to test if the axios put method was called after clicking the submit button.

**I have the following in my __mocks__/axios.js:**

```js
const defaultResponse = { data: {} };

const __mock = {
  reset() {
    Object.assign(__mock.instance, {
      get: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(defaultResponse)),
      put: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(defaultResponse)),
      post: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(defaultResponse)),
      delete: jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve(defaultResponse)),
      defaults: { headers: { common: {} } },
    });
  },
  instance: {},
};

__mock.reset();

module.exports = {
  __mock,
  create() {
    return __mock.instance;
  },
};
```

**My test looks like so:**

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { render, fireEvent, screen } from '@testing-library/react';
import mockAxios from 'axios';
import Profile from '../Profile/Profile';

describe('Profile', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockAxios.__mock.reset();
  });

  it('renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<Profile />).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it('submits form successfully', () => {
    const { findByLabelText } = render(<Profile />);
    const firstName = findByLabelText('first name');
    firstName.value = 'Michaux';
    const lastName = findByLabelText('last name');
    lastName.value = 'Kelley';
    const email = findByLabelText('email');
    email.value = 'test@test.com';
    const submit = screen.getByText('Submit');
    const { put } = mockAxios.__mock.instance;
    put.mockImplementationOnce(() =>
      Promise.resolve({
        data: {},
      })
    );
    fireEvent.click(submit);
    expect(mockAxios.__mock.instance.put).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    expect(mockAxios.__mock.instance.put).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/');
  });
});
```

**My form is built using formik:**

```jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { withFormik } from 'formik';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { Field } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

import api from '../../api';
import TextInput from '@components/common/forms/TextInput';
import Checkbox from '@components/common/forms/Checkbox';
import CheckboxGroup from '@components/common/forms/CheckboxGroup';
import styles from './profile.module.css';
import commonStyles from '@components/common/common.module.css';
import ForgotPassword from '../ForgotPassword';
import Modal from '@components/Modal/Modal';

const formikEnhancer = withFormik({
  validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
    firstName: Yup.string()
      .min(2, "C'mon, your first name is longer than that")
      .required('First name is required'),
    lastName: Yup.string()
      .min(2, "C'mon, your last name is longer than that")
      .required('Last name is required'),
    email: Yup.string()
      .email('Invalid email address')
      .required('Email is required'),
    currentPassword: Yup.string(),
    password: Yup.string()
      .min(8, 'Password has to be at least 8 characters!')
      .matches(
        /^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#\\$%\\^&\\*])/,
        'Password must contain at least 1 uppercase letter, 1 lowercase letter, 1 number, and 1 special character'
      ),
    confirmPassword: Yup.string().oneOf([Yup.ref('password'), null], 'Passwords must match'),
  }),
  handleSubmit: (payload, { setSubmitting, setErrors, props }) => {
    // TODO: consider putting user in local storage
    const { user } = props;
    api
      .put(`/users/${user.userId}`, payload, {
        withCredentials: true,
      })
      .then(res => {
        toast.success('Your user profile was updated successfully', {
          position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
          hideProgressBar: true,
        });
      })
      .catch(err => {
        toast.error('Something went wrong', {
          position: toast.POSITION.TOP_CENTER,
          hideProgressBar: true,
        });
      });
    setSubmitting(false);
  },
  mapPropsToValues: ({ user }) => ({
    ...user,
  }),
  displayName: 'ProfileForm',
});

class Profile extends Component {
  modalProps = {
    triggerText: 'Forgot Password?',
  };

  modalContent = <ForgotPassword user={{ email: '' }} {...this.props} />;

  render() {
    document.title = 'User Profile';
    const {
      values,
      touched,
      errors,
      handleChange,
      handleBlur,
      handleSubmit,
      isSubmitting,
      isAdmin,
      setFieldValue,
    } = this.props;

    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <h2>Profile</h2>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <TextInput
            id="firstName"
            type="text"
            label="First Name"
            error={touched.firstName && errors.firstName}
            value={values.firstName}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
          />
          <TextInput
            id="lastName"
            type="text"
            label="Last Name"
            error={touched.lastName && errors.lastName}
            value={values.lastName}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
          />
          <TextInput
            id="email"
            type="email"
            label="Email"
            autoComplete="username email"
            error={touched.email && errors.email}
            value={values.email}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
          />
          <TextInput
            id="currentPassword"
            type="password"
            label="Current Password"
            autoComplete="current-password"
            error={touched.currentPassword && errors.currentPassword}
            value={values.currentPassword}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
          />
          <div className={styles.forgotPassword}>
            <Modal
              modalProps={this.modalProps}
              modalContent={this.modalContent}
              modalButtonClassName={commonStyles.modalLinkButton}
              {...this.props}
            />
          </div>
          <TextInput
            id="password"
            type="password"
            label="New Password"
            autoComplete="new-password"
            error={touched.password && errors.password}
            value={values.password}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
          />
          <TextInput
            id="confirmPassword"
            type="password"
            label="Confirm Password"
            autoComplete="new-password"
            error={touched.confirmPassword && errors.confirmPassword}
            value={values.confirmPassword}
            onChange={handleChange}
            onBlur={handleBlur}
          />
          {isAdmin && (
            <React.Fragment>
              <h3>Roles</h3>
              <CheckboxGroup
                id="roles"
                className={styles.roles}
                label="Which of these?"
                value={values.roles}
                onChange={setFieldValue}
              >
                <Field
                  component={Checkbox}
                  name="roles"
                  id="admin"
                  label="Admin"
                  value="admin"
                  defaultChecked={values.roles.includes('admin')}
                />
                <Field
                  component={Checkbox}
                  name="roles"
                  id="user"
                  label="User"
                  value="user"
                  defaultChecked={values.roles.includes('user')}
                />
                <Field
                  component={Checkbox}
                  name="roles"
                  id="family"
                  label="Family"
                  value="family"
                  defaultChecked={values.roles.includes('family')}
                />
                <Field
                  component={Checkbox}
                  name="roles"
                  id="friend"
                  label="Friend"
                  value="friend"
                  defaultChecked={values.roles.includes('friend')}
                />
              </CheckboxGroup>
            </React.Fragment>
          )}
          <button type="submit" disabled={isSubmitting} className="btn btn-primary">
            Submit
          </button>
        </form>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default formikEnhancer(Profile);
```

How do I get the test to tell me if my axios put mock was called?

Comment: Please check my answer below to see if this works for you. I couldn't find the implementation of Jest custom mock that you have, can you provide the source of an example with this kind of implementation? It would be very helpful if you can provide a minimal reproduction repo. Also if you can't, please provide the code of `api.put` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I can now see three issues to your implementation.

1. You create a new Axios instance by using `axios.create`. You'll have also to mock `axios.create` with itself:

```js
axios.create = jest.fn(() => axios);
```

2. The mock implementation is slightly wrong. Using latest Jest and according to the documentation for [Manual Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/manual-mocks), the implementation of the `__mocks__/axios.js` should be like this:

```js
const axios = jest.genMockFromModule('axios');
const defaultResponse = { data: {} };

axios.doMockReset = () => {
  Object.assign(axios, {
    get: jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(defaultResponse)),
    put: jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(defaultResponse)),
    post: jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(defaultResponse)),
    delete: jest.fn().mockImplementationOnce(() => Promise.resolve(defaultResponse)),
    defaults: { headers: { common: {} } },
  });
}

// Add create here.
// There is no need to call doMockReset, it will be called when test starts
axios.create = jest.fn(() => axios);

module.exports = axios;
```

3. Formik calls `handleSubmit` asynchronously and Jest does not wait for it to finish. We can use `@testing-library/react` `waitFor` to wait for the `expect(mockAxios.put).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1)`. Also, have the inputs update the values using the `fireEvent.change` event instead of directly setting the input value:

```js
import { render, fireEvent, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
...

await waitFor(() => {
  fireEvent.change(firstName, {
    target: {
      value: "Michaux"
    }
  });
});

...

await waitFor(() => {
  expect(mockAxios.put).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
});
```

#### The whole test:

```jsx
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
import { render, fireEvent, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import mockAxios from 'axios';
import Profile from '../Profile/Profile';

describe('Profile', () => {
  beforeEach(() => {
    mockAxios.doMockReset();
  });

  it('renders correctly', () => {
    const tree = renderer.create(<Profile />).toJSON();
    expect(tree).toMatchSnapshot();
  });

  it('submits form successfully', async () => {
    // Pass a fake user with formik default values for use in mapPropsToValues,
    // else React will complaint regarding inputs changed
    // from uncontrolled to controlled because of these values initially set to undefined:
    // Warning: A component is changing an uncontrolled input of type text to be controlled

    const user = { userId: 1, firstName: '', lastName: '', email: '' };

    const { getByText, getByLabelText } = render(<Profile user={user} />);

    const firstName = getByLabelText(/first name/i);
    const lastName = getByLabelText(/last name/i);
    const email = getByLabelText(/email/i);
    const submit = getByText('Submit');

    await waitFor(() => {
      fireEvent.change(firstName, {
        target: {
          value: "Michaux"
        }
      });
    });

    await waitFor(() => {
      fireEvent.change(lastName, {
        target: {
          value: "Kelley"
        }
      });
    });

    await waitFor(() => {
      fireEvent.change(email, {
        target: {
          value: "test@test.com"
        }
      });
    });

    fireEvent.click(submit);

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(mockAxios.put).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
    })
  });
});
```

Comment: ```expect(mockAxios.put).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);``` doesn't pass

Comment: @mkelley33 what's the error about? Not been called? Can you provide a repo or a minimal repro example? I can upload the code to a Github repository for you to see it's working.

Comment: it's not being called.  I've pushed the repo here https://github.com/mkelley33/pws-gatsby

Comment: @mkelley33 please read my updated answer and also merge this [PR](https://github.com/mkelley33/pws-gatsby/pull/1) and try to run the test again.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's one flaw to this test: the form validation is never triggered.  In fact, you don't even need to set the fields in order to get this test to pass, so it's sort of a false positive.

Comment: I'm checking it. I suspect this has to do with the input element `change` event but I'm not sure yet.

Comment: @mkelley33 I have changed the test code to set the input values using the `fireEvent.change` instead of directly changing the values. The test now passes and it runs validation. It will not pass if you set for example an invalid email. Please merge and check this [PR](https://github.com/mkelley33/pws-gatsby/pull/2).